# Dailymotion doesn't let me upload 10 video per day or even a week

Tags: dailymotion-api

We have been given a upload limit of 10 videos per day and the limit is 2gm within 60 mins per vidoe right but no matter after how long 1 week 1 month if i start uploading videos the max it allows me to upload only 2-3 never more than that. please help and fix.

Comment: Hi! You'd better ask dailymotion support about it. Did you try?

Comment: @Mol0ko How should I do that whenever I try they just send me to pre made question answers.